# need to return maximum value among multiple records with same key using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a VBA function that will search for a value in a column(say column C) in a table. This column can have duplicates. So my search needs to get all the records that match the value (including duplicates) and from these records i need to return only one value among records fetched that has maximum in another column in the same sheet(say column G).

Eg :

```
sno    dept    name     marks
1      cs      sush     55
2      ece     ram      68
3      cs      harish   77
```

So if i give "cs" value to search it must give me 77 as output. I tried to write my own Lookup function but isn't working and getting #value.

Comment: can you provide screenshot of your excel which has the data?

Comment: As Eg. I have added a line...it's the records in excel...each record is seperated by /br

Comment: @user2063626 : I have added a line as (eg)...it's the records in excel...each record is seperated by /br

Comment: i need a screenshot of your data to help you

Comment: @user2063626 how can i add a screen shot to this question. I have the image with me..i'm desperately needing a help on this..

Answer (score 0):

```
Function search(criteria As String)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    Range("Z1").CurrentRegion.Clear
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        rng.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, "", Range("Z1"), True
        Range("AC1").Sort Key1:=Range("AA1"), Key2:=Range("AC1"), Header:=xlYes, Order2:=xlDescending
    End If



    search = Application.VLookup(criteria, Range("AA:AC"), 3, 0)

End Function
```

Comment: I have to give argument to the function that will be the "dept" value : cs and it must return highest "marks" . But ur function is not having any return value. This highest "marks" value should be returned to another sheet say "highest mark for dept" sheet. Can u write a much more simpler code as example and i'm new to VBA. Efficiency is not a constraint for me. Just the correctness of formulae. I was trying to use for loop in searching and getting the row and loading the max in a variable. Returning the max finally back. Can u help me in this approach ??

Comment: The code is working but i got some other way to do this...=MAX(IF($B$2:$B$100=F2,$D$2:$D$100)) ...This formulae helped me out and i used this in VBA..working well..All u have to do is press ctrl+shift_enter